# Why higher-order types are transitive but types of programs are not?

Tags: coq

This may seem like a silly question, but I'm wondering why specification types (e.g. `nat`) "inherits" the `Set` type (and `Type` type), while types of programs do not? What is this inclusivness used for?

Example program:

```
> Check (1 : nat).
1 : nat
> Check (nat : Set).
nat : Set
> Check (Set : Type).
Set : Type
> Check (nat : Type).
nat : Type
> Check (1 : Set).
Error: The term "1" has type "nat" while it is expected to have type "Set".
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1` doesn't have type `Set` because it isn't a type.
There is no inheritance or anything like this, you don't have `A : Set` implies `A : Type`
because `Set : Type` but because `Set` is a *subtype* of `Type`.

This is called **cumulativity** in the case of Coq, and it applies only to universes.
Universes like `Type`, `Prop` or `Set` are types of types.